# Does a function $f$ exists such that: $f(n-k) \ne \Theta(f(n))$ for some constant $k\geq1$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I have encountered the following question in my homework assignment in Data Structures course:

"Does a function $f$ exists such that: $f(n-k) \ne \Theta(f(n))$ for some constant $k\geq1$ ?"

I think no such function $f$ exists, but I do not know how to prove it (or give a counter-example if one exists).

Comment: For example, let $f(n)=n$ if $n$ is a square and $f(n)=1$ otherwise. For every $k\ge1$, $f(n-k) \ne \Theta(f(n))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is $f(n) = 2 ^ {2^n}$. Now, $f(n-1) = 2 ^ {2^{n-1}}$ and we have $\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)} = \frac{1}{2^{2^n - 2^{n-1}}} = \frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$. Hence, $f(n-1) \not \in \Theta(f(n))$. In this example, $k = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample: $f(n)=n!$ As $f(n)$ is $n$ times bigger  than $f(n-1)$, it is clear that $f(n-1) \neq \Theta(f(n))$.